# return original and new value from accessor in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am  thinking about using an accessor on one of my models to "prettify" a name. is it possible to return both the pretty and original version of a field using an accessor? if an accessor is not right for this, how could this been done.

code:

Model:

```
class Application extends \Eloquent {

   protected $guarded = array();
   protected $table = 'apps';

   public function getNameAttribute($value) {
      //some code to prettify         
   }

}
```

currently I am getting this result:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "myapp",
}
```

I would like to get the result as follows:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "myapp",
"prettyname": "MyApp"
}
```

I am not asking about how to capitalize the letters(I know how to do this), I am asking how to return a new field containing the pretty name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Application extends \Eloquent {

    protected $appends = ['prettyname'];

    public function getPrettynameAttribute()
    {
        $name = $this->attributes['name'];

        // some code to prettify $name

        return $name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more clean way to go about this is to use a Presenter.
You're model shouldn't really know about how to display the name to the user. as well as looking at the controller or view code this would seem like your model would have a settable field prettyName which is stored in DB...

You can extract this functionality to a presenter [Laracasts/Presenter](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter)

in your view the would look as follows

```
$myApp->present()->name();
```